# How can I invoke an action after a CiviCRM triggering event?

Tags: actions, events, workflow

If I want to have a certain action taken after a CiviCRM 'trigger', what is the best approach? I'm a Drupal developer used to using Drupal workflows on CiviCRM actions, and I am unfamiliar with WordPress workflow frameworks.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I'm afraid 3rd party plugins/themes are off topic. You might have a better luck asking the plugin author (vendor). ps: I wonder if these [CiviCRM WordPress Hook Tests](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-hook-tester) helps?

Comment: So this is only for core WordPress development, not for finding plugins to help build something in WordPress? I thought I'd seen questions looking for best plugin for x or y. Sorry.